# position is messed up when I save quit my project

Tags: modeling

My question is simple, I am modeling a tank and every thing was perfect since I hit arrow on my keyboard which messed positioning on my elements. I tried to put everything in the right place but whenever I save, quit and reopen my project everything is messed up again. what am I doing wrong ?

[image]

thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you have accidentally added some [keyframes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33057/5705) to your object's location (done by pressing <kbd>I</kbd>).  If this is correct the *Timeline* view should look something like this, with little yellow bars at the keyframes:

[image]

Because the object's location is keyframed, its position is defined by the animation curve between the keyframes.  If you move the object (without setting a new keyframe for that location) and then change frames or play the animation, Blender will automatically snap the object back to its proper position in the animation.

Pressing the <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>></kbd> arrow keys will advance the animation by one frame left or right, the <kbd>^</kbd> or <kbd>v</kbd> keys will advance to the next or previous keyframes.

There are two ways to remove keyframes.  You can go to each individual frame with a keyframe and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> > *Delete Keyframe*.  Or you can go to the *Graph Editor* or *Dope Sheet*, select all the keyframes with <kbd>A</kbd>, and press <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Keyframes*.

[image]